# Выгрузка сайта на хостинг Yii2 basic

Tags: php, yii2, yii, vps

Первый раз переношу сайт из локального сервера на  тестовый хостинг , но не знаю как правильно его там настроить ,чтобы оно хоть что-то показывало .На хостинге возникают такие ошибки
Cannot serve directory /var/www/artem-y/data/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive  -  на самой странице 403 ошибка Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
В папке web файл  .htaccess

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Возьми вдс в аренду за 300 руб/мес. Поставь nginx, а то с этим апачем всю жизнь себе испортишь.

Comment: У вас домен ссылается на корневую папку. Либо настройте домен, чтобы он ссылался на web, либо настройте .htaccess в корневой папке для перенаправления в папку web